# Does anyone know what the figure legend means?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dK41A.png)

Hello!I am reading a paper recently,I cannot figure out what legend means(within rectangle and to the right of figure).Does anyone figure it out?

Comment: Impossible to tell, without the context. Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: At a guess (and it's just a guess) it is looking at the error.  That is to say, you have fitted a curve to some data and you'd like to know that the distance between the actual and the predicted data is near 0.  But, really, there's not a lot to work with here.

Comment: [link](http://visal.cs.cityu.edu.hk/static/pubs/journal/tip12-pedcount.pdf).Original figures is on page 6,Thank you!

Comment: May it involve confidence region?Original paper seems not to explain this legend

Comment: My guess from the context of the paper is that darker background within the band means better fit to the model. Compare in particular panels (a) and (b) in the figure at the top of the 6th pg.